# How do I set the launch image to landscape on iPad in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, ipad, swift, ios8, xcode6

I am making an iOS 8 app written in Swift using Xcode 6. The app is going to run only in landscape mode. The only issue I am having is the launch image file 'storyboard' (.xib) is launching in portrait mode and the rest of the app is fine. I only have the problem on iPad, the iPhone launches the launch image file fine. I even have Landscape selected in the right pane:

[image]

Comment: The orientation in the screenshots does nothing, it for displaying in Xcode only. You need to set the correct available orientations in the `info.plist`

Answer (score 0):

Click on your project in the project navigation and go in the general tab and in Device orientation choose landscape